# ajax onreadystatechange function not being call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Why is this code not working (when calling the handleRequestStateChange function)?:

```
function ajaxRequest(){ 
 var xmlObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlObj.open("GET","1.php",true);
 xmlObj.onreadystatechange = handleRequestStateChange;
 xmlObj.send(null);
}

var handleRequestStateChange = function(){  
    if(xmlObj.readyState == 4 && xmlObj.status==200){
        alert("if loaded");
    }
}
```

but this one is(without calling the handleRequestStateChange function):

```
function ajaxRequest(){

 var xmlObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlObj.open("GET","1.php",true);

 xmlObj.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlObj.readyState == 4 && xmlObj.status==200){
            alert("if loaded");
    }
 }
 xmlObj.send(null);}
```

Comment: In the first example, at the time you say `xmlObj.onreadystatechange = handleRequestStateChange;`, the variable `handleRequestStateChange;` has no value. It is only assigned a value a few statements later when you declare it to be a function.

Comment: I am not sure @JonathanM is correct, since through variable hoisting/late calling the callback could be defined depending on when you call `ajaxRequest`, but in `handleRequestStateChange` you reference `xmlObj` and even if the request is added correctly, that variable is out of scope and therefore undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case, the problem is simply in the scope of the variables, and in this case, `ajaxRequest` can "see" `handleRequestStateChange` but `handleRequestStateChange` cannot "see" `xmlObj`. In the second example, the anonymous function can see `xmlObject` because it's "inside" `ajaxRequest`.

A good place to start is this stackoverflow answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/500459/1480215

For example, removing the `var` actually fixes the first code (not that that's a good idea).

```
function ajaxRequest(){ 
  xmlObj = new XMLHttpRequest(); //suddenly global scope
  xmlObj.open("GET","1.php",true);
  xmlObj.onreadystatechange = handleRequestStateChange;
  xmlObj.send(null);
}

var handleRequestStateChange = function(){  
  if(xmlObj.readyState == 4 && xmlObj.status==200){
    alert("if loaded");
  }
}
```

The code below would also work

```
function ajaxRequest(){ 
  var xmlObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var handleRequestStateChange = function(){  
    if(xmlObj.readyState == 4 && xmlObj.status==200){
      alert("if loaded");
    }
  }
  xmlObj.open("GET","1.php",true);
  xmlObj.onreadystatechange = handleRequestStateChange;
  xmlObj.send(null);
  //but not if var handleRequestStateChange is here
  //due to https://stackoverflow.com/a/336868/1480215
}
```

For completeness I'll also include the snippet below which should work

```
function ajaxRequest(){ 
  var xmlObj = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlObj.open("GET","fragments.htm",true);
  xmlObj.onreadystatechange = handleRequestStateChange;
  xmlObj.send(null);

  function handleRequestStateChange(){ //this will work instead of var funcName=function(){}
    if(xmlObj.readyState == 4 && xmlObj.status==200){
      alert("if loaded");
    }
  }    
}
```

If we are talking about strictly `xmlHttpRequest` events (or events in general) then it's also possible to use the passed event argument.

```
function ajaxRequest(){ 
  var xmlObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlObj.open("GET","1.php",true);
  xmlObj.onreadystatechange = handleRequestStateChange;
  xmlObj.send(null);
}

var handleRequestStateChange=function(event){   //event handlers passes this, generally
  var xmlObj=event.target || event.srcElement   //for compatibility
  //but just having XMLHttpRequest(), is not fully cross-platform anyway
  if(xmlObj.readyState == 4 && xmlObj.status==200){
    alert("if loaded");
  }
}
```

Moving forward, I think it might be a good idea to use a small existing ajax snippet or library like http://www.openjs.com/scripts/jx/. Maybe even jQuery which also has RPC (including `<script>`s to include scripts from other domains without COR)